# MYSQL Sorting By Multiple Join Children

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-order-by, children

I cannot seem to figure out a way to sort sql queries by joined children.

Database Example:

---

Table: **posts**

```
+------+---------+
| id   | title   |
+------+---------+
| 0    |'title1' |
| 1    |'title2' |
| 2    |'title3' |
+------+---------+
```

---

Table: **post_meta**

```
+------+---------+----------+---------+
| id   | post_id | key      | value   |
+------+---------+----------+---------+
| 0    |0        |'coolness'| 5       |
| 1    |0        |'desc'    |'random' |
| 2    |0        |'author'  |'bill'   |
| 3    |1        |'coolness'| 2       |
| 4    |1        |'desc  '  |'random' |
| 5    |2        |'author'  |'joe'    |
| 6    |2        |'coolness'| 9       |
+------+---------+----------+---------+
```

---

I want a list of posts (or just post ids) ordered by their 'coolness' meta number (asc or desc). I dont know if I should be selecting from the posts table and joining on the meta table, or vise-versa. When I join on the post_meta table I only get data from one of the meta rows, so if I just add an order by post_meta.coolness nothing happens.

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the `id`, you can use the `post_meta` table:

```
select pm.post_id
from post_meta pm
where pm.key = 'coolness'
order by pm.value + 0;
```

The `+ 0` is to convert the value (presumably a string) to a number.

If you need other columns related to the post, you can join in the `posts` table.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My database schema is a bit more complicated than the example I posted.  Your query would work great except I also need to query by other meta values. For example: all posts that have meta author -> 'name' ordered by coolness. It would be nice to be able to query by any/multiple meta value as if it was a column in the post table. IE: Get all posts with desc = 'random and author = 'name'  and etc. ordered by coolness.

Comment: @magnito . . . You should ask *another* question, and not merely edit your original question.  Your full question is quite different from what you asked.

Comment: Indeed, your reply does answer my original question.